# Paperclip tries to upload image with content length 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm trying to upload an image using paperclip and the AWS S3 storage

I've set the default configuration for paperclip

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :bucket => '<bucket_name>',
  :s3_credentials => Rails.root.join('config', 'aws.yml').to_s
}
```

In my model i have this

```
as_attached_file :img, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumbnail => "100x100>" }, :path => "assets/products/:attachment/:id/:style.:extension"
```

In the controller i have a simple property update because my model is first created and after the images are uploaded :

```
def upload_thumbnail
   @product = Product.find(params[:id])

   if @product.update_attribute(:img, params[:image])
    render :json => { :done => true, :img_path => @product.img.url }
   else
    render :json => @product.errors }
   end
end
```

When i upload an image i get in the console this error

```
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
[paperclip] saving assets/products/imgs/10/original.jpg
[AWS S3 200 4.134236 3 retries] put_object(:acl=>:public_read,:bucket_name=>"<bucket_name>",:content_length=>0,:content_type=>"image/jpeg",:data=>Paperclip::UploadedFilAdapter: image.jpg,:key=>"assets/products/imgs/10/original.jpg") AWS::Core::Client::NetworkError AWS::Core::Client::NetworkError
```

Looking in S3 the image is created at the path specify by has the size set to 0 bytes.
Also I've notice that i get this when the plugin is trying to resize the image

```
[paperclip] Error while determining content type: Cocaine::CommandNotFoundError
```

but the original image should be uploaded correct. 
What i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you find a workaround or fix?

Comment: No, but after some looking in to the problem I've decided to switch to carrierwave

Comment: Maybe the `Paperclip.options[:command_path]` is not set or wrong in your config file?!